# My html and css code not working same on github

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

My html and css code work perfectly on my pc but when i push it to github it not doing the same thing. It reads all code correctly. Seeing html and css tags. I refreshed a million times and waited for an hour and still same. I used @keyframes in css and i wanna my text shake. Thats the issue it working on my pc but not on github.
https://github.com/MNFamous/webpage

Comment: Please share the code and link of your repo

Comment: https://github.com/MNFamous/webpage

Comment: The live version https://www.mastess.net seems to work fine. I see you have used 1, 2, 3, 4% That's why it's so fast. Try 10 20 30 and 40 %

Comment: cuz it has to be creepy.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code yet, but https://mnfamous.github.io/webpage/ does shake for me.

Comment: maybe it cause for my extensions ? i deleted all my extensions and still same on my chrome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page a picture of a box cat and a text that shakes every couple of seconds? If that's so, it's working fine at least in my mobile.

Comment: yeah thats the real one but on my chrome it doesnt. bruhh maybe its time to update my chrome.

Comment: But how do you ran it locally when testing? Where did you opened the html?

Comment: i used xampp and directly converting notpad to html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).